# Throwing array out of bounds exception in for loop when array size is unknown (multiplicative persistence)

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm doing a coding challenge online where I'm supposed to write a class that takes in a positive parameter ("num") and returns its multiplicative persistence. This is the number of times you must multiply the digits in "num" until you reach a single digit.

For example, the multiplicative persistence of 39 = 3. This is because:

1. 3 * 9 = 27
2. 2 * 7 = 14
3. 1 * 4 = 4

This is the whole program so far:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Persist {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        persistence(39);
    }

    public static int persistence(long num) {

        int persistenceValue = 0;
        List<Long> digitList = new ArrayList<Long>();
        long lastDigit;

        //Resolves if num is single digit

        if (num <= 9) {

            return 0;
        }

        //Takes each digit of number and stores it to digitList (backwards)

        while (num > 0) {

            lastDigit = (num % 10);
            digitList.add(lastDigit);
            num = num / 10;
        }

        //Takes each digit in digitList and stores it in array in correct order
        for (Long d : digitList) {

            Long[] currentDigitArray = new Long[digitList.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < currentDigitArray.length; i++) {

                currentDigitArray[currentDigitArray.length - i] = d;
            }

            persistenceValue = currentDigitArray.length;

            while (persistenceValue > 1) {

                List<Long> productList = multiplyDigits(currentDigitArray);
                persistenceValue++;
            }
        }

        return persistenceValue;
    }

    public static List multiplyDigits(Long[] currentDigitArray) {
        //multiplies each digit    

        List<Long> productList = new ArrayList<Long>();

        for (int i = 0; i < currentDigitArray.length; i++) {

            Long product = currentDigitArray[i] * currentDigitArray[i + 1];
            productList.add(product);
        }
        return productList;
    }
}
```

I keep running into an array out of bounds exception for the for loop on line 52:

```
//Takes each digit in digitList and stores it in an array
for (Long d : digitList) {

    Long[] currentDigitArray = new Long[digitList.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < currentDigitArray.length; i++) {

        currentDigitArray[currentDigitArray.length - i] = d; 
        // ^ exception is thrown here ^
    }
```

**So obviously I looked this up on Google like a good stack overflow user.** An array-index out of bounds exception is a Java exception thrown due to the fact that the program is trying to access an element at a position that is outside an array limit, hence the words "Out of bounds."

The problem is that I have no idea how big that array is going to be up front because it's all going to depend on how many digits are passed in by the user. I hard coded 39, but eventually I want the user to be able to put in as many as they want.

So how else would I takes each digit in `digitList` and store it in array?

**This part has been resolved, but now I have a similar problem on line 78:**

```
public static List multiplyDigits(Long[] currentDigitArray) {
    //multiplies each digit    

    List<Long> productList = new ArrayList<Long>();

    for (int i = 0; i < currentDigitArray.length; i++) {
        Long product = currentDigitArray[i] * currentDigitArray[i + 1];
        //^This line here
        productList.add(product);

    }
    return productList;
}
```

I feel like this is a very similar problem, but don't quite know how to fix it.

Comment: You know the array can't be more than 18 digits long and you also don't need to use an array or a list, I would try to use neither.

Comment: `currentDigitArray[currentDigitArray.length - i -1 ] = d;` wiil solve the issue. because on the first iteration it will exceed the limit of the array

Comment: The last element in the array is `currentDigitArray[currentDigitArray.length - i - 1]` as array start at 0.

Comment: `multipleDigits` creates a new `productList` which you discard.

Comment: So this is weird. I tried `currentDigitArray[currentDigitArray.length - i -1 ] = d;` and now I'm getting this:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at Persist.multiplyDigits(Persist.java:78)
 at Persist.persistence(Persist.java:61)
 at Persist.main(Persist.java:19)
/home/work/.cache/netbeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assignment

```
currentDigitArray[currentDigitArray.length - i] = d;
```

should be

```
currentDigitArray[currentDigitArray.length - 1 - i] = d;
```

to avoid the problem.

With this said, you can avoid arrays entirely by performing multiplication as you go. Recall that the order in which you do multiplication does not change the result. Therefore, you can start multiplication from the back of the number, and arrive at the same solution.

Comment: I'm now getting a similar problem in line 78:

`Long product = currentDigitArray[i] * currentDigitArray[i + 1];`

Comment: @DaveCat that's because you need to stop your loop one digit prior to the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are zero-indexed, so `currentDigitArray.length` is always going to be out of bounds. In fact, because of the additive identity property, `currentDigitArray.length - i` is going to be `currentDigitArray.length` when `i` is 0. To fix this, just subtract an extra 1 in your index calculation:

```
currentDigitArray[currentDigitArray.length - i - 1] = d;
```

For your second problem, you iterate one element too many, and you need to stop one element earlier:

```
for (int i = 0; i < currentDigitArray.length - 1; i++) {
```

Comment: This doesnt address the second problem explicitly (indexing i and i+1 when the condition is < list.length), which might be intentional, but is i think and integral part of the solution

Comment: The answer was posted before the second problem came about.